trying to install a data drive for plex
First off I am new to Ubuntu and do not know this system at all but I a a fast learner.  My problem is I just quit windows. I have loaded the latest version of Ubuntu on a clean hard drive on a desktop pc. I am trying to load Plex on my Ubuntu system and I have a disk drive from windows that has all my data files for plex (movies, tv shows, pictures). This drive shows up on my home screen but I cant seem to get the Plex program to see the data files. Please help.

you fail to say what research you have done but you may find this article of some help

Latest is not a version. The latest tomorrow could be a different version. Please edit the question and add the actual version you installed. What is the file system type of this data drive?
